# How do I create a sublist from a larger list to loop through in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I've been trying to wrapped by brain around this for about a day now, and I can't seem to conceptualize a solution for my issue (and perhaps I'm going about this all wrong).

What I'd like to do is take a list of 16 players for a tournament and break them into matchups, like a sublist of the larger tournament list. Say my list looks likes this (but 16 players instead of 4):

```
        IList<TeamModel> tournamentList = new List<TeamModel>();            
        tournamentList.Add(new TeamModel() { ID = 1, Seed = 1, Conference = "Conference 1", TeamName = TruncateTeamName("Team 1") });
        tournamentList.Add(new TeamModel() { ID = 2, Seed = 2, Conference = "Conference 1", TeamName = TruncateTeamName("Team 2") });
        tournamentList.Add(new TeamModel() { ID = 3, Seed = 3, Conference = "Conference 1", TeamName = TruncateTeamName("Team 3") });
        tournamentList.Add(new TeamModel() { ID = 4, Seed = 4, Conference = "Conference 1", TeamName = TruncateTeamName("Team 4") });
```

What I'm doing now is not really working out. I thought that it would be best to iterate over the list using a foreach loop and adding the individual matchups (2 players) into a new list. At that point, I need to access the TeamModel data in Razor, but that's not going to work with how I have this now. But I know I'm thinking about this wrong at this point.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
        IList<TeamMatchup> TeamMatchup = new List<TeamMatchup>();
        List<TeamMatchup> matchup = new List<TeamMatchup>();
        foreach (TeamModel team in tournamentList)
        {                
            if (TeamMatchup.Count == 2)
            {
                matchup.AddRange(TeamMatchup);
                TeamMatchup.Clear();
                if (matchup.Count.Equals(tournamentList.Count / 2))
                    break;
            }
            else
            {

                for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        //TeamMatchup.Add(new TeamMatchup() { TeamA = ??, TeamB = ?? });
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }                        
                }                    
            }                    
        }
        ViewData["Matchup"] = matchup;
        //ViewData["Team"] = //need to add some method to handle the individual matchups

        return View();
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to create match-ups in an elimination bracket like way. So Team 1 vs. Team 2, Team 3 vs Team 4, etc. And not a round robin way.

You can use a for or foreach loop for this. In the code below, I am looping though the list of teams, and if the count is odd adding that team to the the TeamA in the current matchup. If the count is even adding that team to TeamB of the matchup. Then adding the matchup to the list of matchups. Then creating a new currentMatch.

```
        var matchups = new List<TeamMatch>();
        var matchCount = 1; // sets a count
        var currentMatch = new TeamMatch(); // current matchup

        foreach (var team in tournamentList)
        {                
            // Checks if count is an even number.
            if (matchCount % 2 == 0)
            {
                // If an even number, add teamB to matchup, 
                // add current matchup to list and create a new matchup.
                currentMatch.TeamB = team;
                matchups.Add(currentMatch);

                currentMatch = new TeamMatch();
            }
            else
            {
                // If on odd number, add teamA to matchup.
                currentMatch.TeamA = team;
            }

            matchCount++; 
        }

        if (matchCount % 2 == 1)
        {
            //Odd number of total teams, one team isn't matched.
        } 

        // Here is where you can set the viewdata of the matchups.
```

Comment: Yeah, that did what I was looking for. Thanks!